# How do i delete indexes in a DataFrame based of a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say i have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
        year
0       0
1       0
2       0
3       0
4       0
...     ...
17373   1
17374   1
17375   1
17377   1
17378   1
```

How can i drop all the values *1* from the column **year** to get count of occurrences of *1*. The result should look like this:

```
        year
0       0
1       0
2       0
3       0
4       0
```

I tried using df.drop but couldnt make it work.
Thank you!

Comment: `df = df[df['year'] != 1]`

Comment: `df.query('year != 1')`

Comment: Both solutions worked great. Thank you very much!